# Wordpress PHP - How to show header image on each page?

Tags: php, wordpress

There are similar questions to this one asked before, but I tried all of the proposed solutions and it didn't work. My Wordpress site has a header image on the homepage, but it's not showing on every page. I tried using a Unique Headers plugin, tried creating a different .php file for each of my pages to display header images (for example header-about.php), but it didn't work. I found this code in the header.php file which I think needs to be changed, but I'm not very familiar with php. I tried changing with some propositions, but it either didn't do anything or it broke the site.

This is the code for the header image in the header.php file:

```
<div <?php post_class( 'featured-' . $count ); ?>>
                        <!-- Page content stuff end -->
                        <?php if ( is_front_page() ) : ?>
                            <!-- Header img -->
                            <div class="header-content-wrap-outer">
                                <div class="header-content-wrap">
                                    <div class="bottom-header-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                                    <div class="bottom-header-paragraph"> <?php esc_html_e('Written', 'wordly') ?> <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></div>
                                    <!-- Button-->
                                    <div class="buttons-wrapper">
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="header-button-solid"><?php esc_html_e('READ MORE', 'wordly') ?></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--Buttons -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <!-- / Header img -->
                        <!-- Header content end -->
                        <!-- Page content stuff start -->
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    $count++;
                endwhile;
            endif;
            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
            <!-- Page content stuff end -->
            <!-- Header bg start-->
        </header>
```

Comment: There is no ```img``` tag in your "header image" html tags.

Comment: Since img src tag is not present, the image may be set as background image attribute in one of the class. You can confirm via inspect element. Moreover, this function `is_front_page()` is checking for the homepage and rendering the header image. If you want the image to be displayed in all pages uniformly, you can drop this condition and edit your code.